# cursor jump to mouse pointer location

Tags: mouse, touchpad, cursor

as i type, the cursor jump to some other location normally towards mouse pointer location . it also select lot of words at once and deletes.

dell team has given a software to windows and windows7 working ok. but ; i prefer Ubuntu as my os. how to solve this issue ? I am using linux years together. it is new laptop creating issue.

Comment: me too have the same problem on my dell laptop...

Comment: mention more information about your system configuration:
details such as system model,architecture,processor,graphics card..
Etc

Answer (score 1):

Probably the touchpad activating. Try this:

System Settings => Hardware => Input Devices => Touchpad => Taps

and change 'One Finger' under 'Mouse Click Emulation' to 'No action'

Comment: I just downgraded Ubuntu 14 to ubuntu13.  Now ok.